# How can I access the wchar_t of a wchar_t*?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

This is my code:

```
   wchar_t wbuffer[512];
   wchar_t* wc = (wchar_t*) malloc(buffer_size);
   int buflen = 0;

// ... stuff


// inside the while loop
   wbuffer[buflen] = (wchar_t)wc;
```

what is wrong with this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that ... whats going wrong?

Comment: Maybe wbuffer[buflen] = *wc; or  wbuffer[buflen] = *(wc + i); ? or  wbuffer[buflen] = wc[0];

Comment: Shall anyone guess or are you willing to provide the missing details? (defintion of buffer_size, the code that fills wc before, the while loop, the code modifying buflen,...)

Comment: @Simon: I'm obviously blind ;)

Comment: The question is missing important details. What do you hope to accomplish and how does it differ from the behaviour you observed?

Comment: @coolface: and by "empty", you mean what, exactly?

Comment: All the casts are pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereference wc within your loop.

```
wbuffer[buflen] = *wc;
```

Comment: It was there in an example for reading from a socket as a multibyte character.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is `buffer_size`? Is it multiple of `sizeof(wchar_t)`? If not, make it!

Second, `wc` is a pointer to `wchar_t`, that means, you can access `wchar_t` of it as `wc[index]`, where maximum value of `index` can be `buffer_size/size(wchar_t) - 1`. You code should be something like this:

```
//this 'if' is needed if you don't have any idea of what buffer_size could be!
if (buffer_size % sizeof(wchar_t))
       buffer_size = (buffer_size / sizeof(wchar_t) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);

wchar_t wbuffer[512];
wchar_t* wc = (wchar_t*) malloc(buffer_size);
int buflen = 0;
int maxindex = buffer_size/ sizeof(wchar_t) - 1;
int index = 0;
while ( index <= maxindex)
{
   //use wc[index]; here
    index++; //last line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to do.

1. wbuffer is uninitialized
2. you're trying to store the pointer to a wchar_t into an array of wchar_t

Please explain the purpose of the program.

Answer (score 0):

`wc` variable in your case is a pointer which points to the memory that contains arrays of wide characters. If you want get some wide character via `wc` variable you should write something like

```
wbuffer[buflen] = (wchar_t)wc[0];//here you assign first wide character of wc to first wide char of wbuffer, if buflen == 0
```